# Configure the Drupal 6 module to appear only on home page

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, configure

I am building a drupal 6 module.

I want to code it such a way that it shows up only on the home screen of the website when someone enables it.
What should I add and where?

Comment: You should create an answer and select it as accepted answer. It's better for the site's organization. And you'll get a badge too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Basically in YOURMODULE.module file  add the following condition

if(drupal_is_front_page()) 

{

//display conditions

}